# SQL error or missing database (near "?": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite

Would you be that kind and tell me whats wrong in here? `conn` is `DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL)`

```
        try {
            PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE week SET ?=? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?");
            prepStmt.setString(1, s);
            prepStmt.setFloat(2, x);
            prepStmt.setInt(3, c);
            prepStmt.setInt(4, d);
            prepStmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during data update");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error is in first line of "try" and it goes like "SQL error or missing database (near "?": syntax error)". I have to add that when I put this statement in cmd with "?" substituted with values it works as charm.

Comment: use `PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE week SET "+s+"=? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a column name to the `PreparedStatement`. What you could do to overcome this is change it in the string.

```
try {
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "UPDATE week SET " + s + " =? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?");
    prepStmt.setFloat(1, x);
    prepStmt.setInt(2, c);
    prepStmt.setInt(3, d);
    prepStmt.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("Error during data update");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ok but can't i just do it like this: 'String stmt="UPDATE week SET "+s+" = "+String.valueOf(x)+" WHERE id>= "+String.valueOf(c)+" AND id<="+String.valueOf(d);'

Comment: or even better: 'String stmt="UPDATE week SET "+s+" = "+x+" WHERE id>= "+c+" AND id<= "+d;'?

Comment: You can do it, but it is a good practice to pass parameters, it helps preventing SQL Injection (not quite sure... someone correct me if I'm wrong, please). Also, looking at the code I've posted, building the string this way may be a potential security flaw. Try doing it statically, using a flag to define the column name. E.g
`if (foo_flag) s= "column_1"` (...)

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass column names as parameters to the prepared statement. You can only pass values as parameters :

```
    try {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE week SET some_column_name=? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?");
        prepStmt.setFloat(1, x);
        prepStmt.setInt(2, c);
        prepStmt.setInt(3, d);
        prepStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error during data update");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do ? = ? you should specify the field id = ?...or whatever field you want there.

```
PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE week SET columnName=? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?");
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned you can not pass **column names** or **sql syntax** to the `PreparedStatement`. however you can use `String.format()` to pass anything to your sql:

```
try {
                String sql = "UPDATE week SET %s=? WHERE id>=? AND id<=?";
                sql = String.format(sql , "s")
                PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                prepStmt.setFloat(1, x);
                prepStmt.setInt(2, c);
                prepStmt.setInt(3, d);
                prepStmt.executeUpdate();
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Error during data update");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

sa you can see `? = ?` is replaced with `%s = ?` and later the column name was replaced with `String.format` and later the String was passed to the `PreparedStatement`.
however this should not be used pass data because it defies the purpose of `PreparedStatement`s.